# MariaDB 10.1 and ODB from codesynthesis

Tags: mariadb, odb

Currently, I am working with ODB from codesynthesis and MySQL (Oracle) databases. 
I want to switch to MariaDB. Is ODB from codesynthesis working with the latest version of MariaDB (10.1) or do I have to install the 5.5.45 version?

Comment: See my answer
--Nevermind
I recommend you ask this question on the official mailing list of ODB, since the authors are replying it on an almost daily basis.
--Nevermind

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official website](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/odb/features.xhtml):

> Databases
>
> MySQL runtime
>          Supports MySQL/MariaDB 5.0.3 and later.

So yes.